# Can't access python after packaging electron app Error: spawn python ENOENT

Tags: node.js, permissions, electron, child-process, electron-builder

I've got my app all ready to go and it works perfectly running with npm start (equivalent to electron .), but when I package the app with electron builder I no longer have access to python. The script won't run and it gives the error "Error: spawn python ENOENT". The rest of the app works fine, but I don't have access to the python functionality. I have been at this for a few hours to no avail. Below is where the python is called in main.js, pythonPath is where python is I have double checked. Originally I didn't have an env parameter at all but this was a suggested solution on another forum, it didn't work.

```js
const pythonPath = '/Users/myname/miniconda3/bin/python'; 
log.info("process.env.PYTHON_PATH", process.env.PYTHON_PATH)
const env = Object.create(process.env);
env.PATH = `${pythonPath}:${env.PATH}`;
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const pythonProcess = spawn('python', [path.join(process.resourcesPath, '../flask-server/server.py')], {
    env: env
});
```

First I thought the file path was wrong after build so added some tests and discovered the path is correct and it exists (path to the .py file that is). Next I thought maybe something was wrong with the python evaluation so I switched to an exec where I was calling "python -c path/to/my/file.py" directly. With that I got the error "Error executing Python script: ...  python: command not found". This leads me to believe that for whatever reason, node.js is able to access my computer's python when I run the dev version, but after build something changes and it can no longer access python. I've checked file permissions and that didn't change anything either. Thanks in advance for the help.

package.json:

```json
{
    "name": "app-name",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "app description",
    "main": "main.js",
    "author": "Rocky",
    "license": "MIT",
    "devDependencies": {
        "electron": "^27.1.3",
        "electron-builder": "^24.9.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "electron .",
        "package": "electron-builder"
    },
    "build": {
        "appId": "app-name",
        "directories": {
            "output": "dist"
        },
        "extraFiles": [
            {
                "from": "flask-server",
                "to": "flask-server",
                "filter": [
                    "**/*"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "win": {
            "target": "nsis",
            "icon": "windows_icon.ico"
        },
        "mac": {
            "target": "dmg",
            "icon": "mac_icon.icns"
        },
        "linux": {
            "target": "AppImage"
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "electron-log": "^5.0.1",
        "fix-path": "^4.0.0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For any with a similar issue, I was unable to resolve this error, but I found a workaround in including the python executable as an extraFile. This app had some heavy python logic so I included my entire miniconda folder, modifying package.json by adding the following to the extraFiles section

```json
"extraFiles": [
    {
        "from": "flask-server",
        "to": "flask-server",
        "filter": [
            "**/*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "from": "miniconda3",
        "to": "miniconda3",
        "filter": [
            "**/*"
        ]
    }
],
```

to access these files in the packaged/ deployed app (with electron-builder, from `main.js`), I used

```js
const pythonPath = path.join(process.resourcesPath, '../miniconda3/bin/python');
const env = Object.create(process.env);
env.PATH = `${pythonPath}:${env.PATH}`;
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const pythonProcess = spawn(pythonPath, [path.join(process.resourcesPath, '../flask-server/server.py')], {
    env: env
});
```

paths change a bit in production and process.resourcesPath will always return the path to the resources folder in the packaged app. Hope this helps.