Error Executing Python Script in Packaged Electron App on macOS
I am developing an Electron application that executes a Python script using child_process. While everything runs perfectly in the local development environment, I encounter an error when running the packaged application on macOS. The error occurs when trying to execute the Python executable.
Note- I've added the executable python compiler in the source code itself , resources/python3.10.
Command failed: "/Volumes/YourAppName 1.0.0-arm64/YourAppName.app/Contents/Resources/resources/python3.10" 
/bin/sh: /Volumes/YourAppName 1.0.0-arm64/YourAppName.app/Contents/Resources/resources/python3.10: No such file or directory
Relevant Code: this is my index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Run Python Script</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Python Script Runner</h1>
    <button id="runPython">Train Model</button>
    <p id="output">Output will appear here...</p>
    <script>
        const { exec } = require('child_process');
        const path = require('path');
        const fs = require('fs');

        document.getElementById('runPython').addEventListener('click', () => {
            let pythonExecutable = path.join(__dirname, 'resources', 'python3.10');
            if (!fs.existsSync(pythonExecutable)) {
                pythonExecutable = path.join(process.resourcesPath, 'resources', 'python3.10');
            }

            const appScriptPath = path.join(__dirname, 'app.py');
            const command = `"${pythonExecutable}" "${appScriptPath}"`;

            exec(command, {shell: true}, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                if (error) {
                    document.getElementById('output').innerText = `Error: ${error.message}`;
                    return;
                }
                if (stderr) {
                    document.getElementById('output').innerText = `stderr: ${stderr}`;
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    const output = stdout.toString();
                    console.log('Received output from Python:', output);
                    document.getElementById('output').innerText = `Output: ${output}`;
                } catch (e) {
                    console.error('Error parsing JSON:', e);
                    document.getElementById('output').innerText = 'Error parsing JSON output from Python script.';
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

{
  "name": "electron-tensorflow",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron . ",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "package": "electron-builder ",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.example.yourapp",
    "productName": "YourAppName",
    "directories": {
      "output": "dist"
    },
    "files": [
      "index.js",
      "index.html",
      "build/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*",
      "package.json"
    ],
    "extraResources": [
      {
        "from": "./resources/",
        "to": "resources",
        "filter": ["**/*"]
      }
    ],
    "asar": true,
    "mac": {
      "category": "public.app-category.utilities"
    },
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis",
      "icon": "build/icon.ico"
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": "AppImage",
      "icon": "build"
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.24.1",
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-fuses": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron/fuses": "^1.8.0",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "electron": "^30.0.2",
    "electron-builder": "^23.0.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.6.0",
    "webpack": "^5.91.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^5.0.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-reload": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1"
  }
}


Setup Details:

Electron Version: (specify version)
Electron Packager: Used for creating the DMG file (macOS)

The application is designed to train a model in Python, which is a critical requirement for my project. I am using electron-packager for packaging.
Question:
I am new to Electron and am unsure why the path error occurs post-packaging but not during local development. Could someone help identify what I might be missing, or suggest what should be checked or changed in the setup?

Check your python3 path and update.

I've added an executable Python compiler to the /resources/python3.10 directory.
and it is working fine locally. while packaging it is (the executable python compiler) being moved to /Users/divakaryadav/Documents/electron-tensorflow/dist/mac-arm64/YourAppName.app/Contents/Resources/resources/python3.10
but it's is not able to get executed.

Got it. Please setup a python path like this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77617181/cant-access-python-after-packaging-electron-app-error-spawn-python-enoent

He is using the system's default Python installation. In contrast, I am using a custom version: an executable Python compiler that I've added into the source code and given it's path to exec of the child process.
